# Cannot create text data type in Mariadb Columnstore

Tags: sql, mariadb, create-table, columnstore

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/columnstore-create-table/

Says this, and it works..

`` DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `orders`;
  CREATE TABLE orders (
  orderkey INTEGER, 
  customer VARCHAR(45)
) ENGINE=ColumnStore; ``

This page says that TEXT  data type is supported.

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/columnstore-data-types/

ColumnStore supports the following data types: TEXT

but this doesn't work..

`` DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `orders`;
  CREATE TABLE orders (
  orderkey INTEGER, 
  customer TEXT
) ENGINE=ColumnStore; ``

`ERROR 1178 (42000): The storage engine for the table doesn't support The syntax or the data type(s) is not supported by Columnstore. Please check the Columnstore syntax guide for supported syntax or data types.`

I am running 1.0.11. I get it like so:
`wget https://downloads.mariadb.com/enterprise/htxx-hpee/mariadb-columnstore/1.0.11/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary_amd64/mariadb-columnstore-1.0.11-1-xenial.x86_64.deb.tar.gz`

My installation code is here:

`https://github.com/dgleba/vamp206a/blob/master/apps/mcs/mariadbcolumnstore-step1.sh#L84`

I run `a2/24start.sh` then `/apps/mcs/mariadbcolumnstore-step1.sh` and then follow the commands in `...step2.sh`

Can anyone shed any light on the fact that docs say TEXT is supported, but I am getting this error?

Comment: What version are you running?

Comment: I am running 1.0.11. I get it like so.. https://github.com/dgleba/vamp206a/blob/master/apps/mcs/mariadbcolumnstore-step1.sh#L84

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/columnstore-data-types/ says that `TEXT` and `BLOB` are not supported until ColumnStore version 1.1.0.

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mariadb-columnstore-11-release-notes/ says that 1.1.0 was released 2017-09-18.

Meanwhile, consider using `VARCHAR(...)` -- up to 8000 seems to be allowed.

Comment: Thanks, I certainly missed that statement about 1.1.0.